# how to do some action(like create database) while deploying the war file(java) into tomcat server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

At the time of deploying the war(java war file) file into the tomcat server, I want to create table and insert data into table (i am using mysql).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you've tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options :

- you could deploy your application with a script (like an Apache Ant script) and include the necessary SQL code to create and populate your database
- You can also check for the existence of the table at startup of the application and create it if needed. [This article](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html) suggests some options to perform tasks at startup of a web application.